# Skip spelling in Emacs for the content of a user macro

Tags: macros, emacs, auctex, spelling

In Emacs, in order to skip spelling for the arguments of a user macro, one appends an entry to the `ispell-tex-skip-alists` variable.

For example, to skip parsing the argument of `\mycommad`, one adds an entry like

```lisp
("\\\\mycommad"    ispell-tex-arg-end)
```

The complete command, perhaps in the init file, should be

```lisp
(setq ispell-tex-skip-alists
   (list
    (append
     (car ispell-tex-skip-alists) ;tell ispell to ignore content of this:
     '(("\\\\mycommad"       ispell-tex-arg-end)))
(cadr ispell-tex-skip-alists)))
```

So the text inside   `\mycommad{blah blah}` will be skipped.

But what if the command takes two arguments and I want to skip only the spelling of the second? That is

```
\mycommad{spell this}{skip this}
```

Documentation for using `ispell-tex-skip-alists` is very limited. Particularly, `ispell-tex-arg-end` sometime  takes a numeric argument, what is it?

Comment: `ispell-tex-arg-end` takes as argument the number of the first mandatory argument to spell. E.g., `("\\\\addcontentsline" ispell-tex-arg-end 2)` means that the first mandatory argument will be skipped, the second (and following) will be spelled.

Comment: +1 @giordano: I was looking for spelling the first and skipping the second. So `ispell-tex-arg-end 1` should be skip none and spell everything starting from the first. I have seen also  `ispell-tex-arg-end 0`, what is it for? And, please, where can I find documentation for this topic? The .el file is very limited.

Comment: I've just read definition of `ispell-tex-arg-end`, in `ispell.tex`. You can find it with `C-h f ispell-tex-arg-end RET`. I have to correct: the argument of `ispell-tex-arg-end` is the first argument to spell minus one. The first argument of `\addcontentsline` to be spelled will be the third. I suppose that a `0` arg means "spell all arguments", though it looks strange to me. I don't know how to do what you want.

Comment: In any case I have a partial solution, as I could swap the macro arguments. As for the zero, in `ispell.el` I found: `("\\\\makebox" ispell-tex-arg-end 0)`.

Comment: maybe `0` means to skip optional arguments, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Theory

This is a long answer to using `ispell-tex-skip-alists` and `ispell-tex-arg-end`, but you might want to go straight to the proposed solutions.

Upon examination of `ispell.el` Lisp code in Emacs, I found what follows.

The skip command template to append to your Emacs init file is:

```lisp
(setq ispell-tex-skip-alists
      (list
       (append
    (car ispell-tex-skip-alists) 
    '(
      ("\\\\mycommand"       ispell-tex-arg-end)
      ("\\\\mycommandtwo"    ispell-tex-arg-end 2)
      ;; add as many lines like the previous two as you need before the "))"  
      ))
       (cadr ispell-tex-skip-alists)))
```

Note that I used an unusual formatting to make line insertion easy for non-Lisp users. Ordinary formatting would be:

```lisp
(setq ispell-tex-skip-alists
      (list
       (append
    (car ispell-tex-skip-alists) 
    '(("\\\\mycommand"       ispell-tex-arg-end)
      ("\\\\mycommandtwo"      ispell-tex-arg-end 2)))
       (cadr ispell-tex-skip-alists)))
```

In the preceding code `\\\\mycommand` is any regular expression identifying the beginning of the text region to be skipped from spelling. If you want to tell Emacs to use a  particular regular expression to mark the ending of the skip region, use a skip line like:

```lisp
("\\\\mycommand"       "myregexp")
```

where `"myregexp"` is a placeholder for your regular expression.

Most often, our command is like: `\mycommand{text to skip}`; therefore the brace `}` is the marker for the skip-region ending and this suggests writing:

```lisp
("\\\\mycommand"       "}")
```

However, in most cases, a LaTeX command might include optional LaTeX arguments in square brackets hosting command parameters that do not need any spelling, such as:

```
\mycommand[skip this][skip this]{text to skip}
```

To skip the content in square brackets, instead of using `"}"` to denote the end of the skip region, you use:

```lisp
("\\\\mycommand"   ispell-tex-arg-end)
```

Formally `ispell-tex-arg-end` is a function built into the spelling library, which causes skipping the spelling of any command arguments in square brackets.

`ispell-tex-arg-end` has also another important feature. Normally a second macro argument will not be skipped, such as in:

```
\mycommand[skip this][skip this]{text to skip}{I will be spell-checked}
```

However, you can override this behaviour by giving an integer argument to `ispell-tex-arg-end`, i.e.:

```lisp
("\\\\mycommand"   ispell-tex-arg-end n)
```

In this case, Emacs spelling will skip `n` braced-arguments of `\mycommand`. Omitting `n` is like passing 1. Also, if `n` is 0, then you will only skip the arguments in square brackets.

The latter feature answers to the second part of the question concerning the use of `ispell-tex-skip-alists` and `ispell-tex-arg-end`.

And now for the more relevant parts.

### Solution 1

Assuming you are the *owner* of `\mycommand`and you can/want to slightly modify it, just redefine it so to swap the arguments. Therefore, it will work like this:

```
\mycommand{skip this}{spell this}
```

Append to your Emacs init file:

```lisp
(setq ispell-tex-skip-alists
      (list
       (append
    (car ispell-tex-skip-alists) 
    '(("\\\\mycommand"   ispell-tex-arg-end 1)))
       (cadr ispell-tex-skip-alists)))
```

Number 1 after `ispell-tex-arg-end` is used for clarity, but you might omit it.

### Solution 2

If redefining `\mycommand`is not an option for you, you can define:

```
\newcommand{\mycommandSpell}[2]{%
\mycommand{#2}{#1}}
```

Append to your Emacs init file:

```lisp
(setq ispell-tex-skip-alists
      (list
       (append
    (car ispell-tex-skip-alists) 
    '(("\\\\mycommandSpell"   ispell-tex-arg-end 1)))
       (cadr ispell-tex-skip-alists)))
```

As for the previous solution, number 1 after `ispell-tex-arg-end` is just used for clarity.

### For the curious

Why are there four slashes in `"\\\\mycommand"` regular expression string?  First you have to double the slash in `\mycommand` to tell to the Lisp interpreter the slash is not there to signify an escape sequence (like the newline "\n").
You have to double the doubled-slash a second time because, in a similar fashion, the regexp engine interprets a single slash like a command suffix, much like in LaTeX. So when you write `\\\\mycommand`, you are telling `\\mycommand` to Lisp and, when Lisp passes `\\mycommand`  to the regexp parser, it will look for the string `"\mycommand"` as is, instead of interpreting "\m" as a command.
Note that to search for a brace, "{", you simply use `{`, but use `\\[` to search for a square bracket.

Comment: In the solutions, is the `2` really correct?  I think it should be `1`, or omitted.

Comment: @TorstenBronger: It was a copy and paste typo, fixed, thank you,