# Ispell in Emacs without a middle mouse button

Tags: emacs, spelling, flyspell

Ispell/Flyspell in Emacs uses the mouse middle button to activate the context menu for a misspelled word. The problem is that my laptop doesn't have a middle button. So is there any way to tell Ispell or emacs to use a different key/button (say Ctrl+Right click) for this purpose? (I use Auctex if that matters.)

Comment: This looks like a good question for http://emacs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Thérèse Yes, but sites in beta are not targets for migration, so it would have to be re-asked.

Comment: What about this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117204/skip-spelling-in-emacs-for-the-content-of-a-user-macro

Comment: Are you on GNU/Linux or another operating system?  On GNU/Linux, middle button is equal to pressing right and left button together.

Comment: I just use `M-$`… I had no idea you could do this with a mouse :P

Comment: @ giordano: You are right and I tried that at first but that can be tricky specially as laptops nowadays have one piece trackpads (The trakpad and its buttons are all one solid surface).

Comment: @Reza (please don't separate the @ and the user name, I won't be notified otherwise): desktop environments usually allow to configure a gesture to replicate the middle button click.  For example, with KDE I set the two-finger tap on the touchpad for that.  The middle button is useful also for other stuff (e.g. X clipboard), don't miss it `;-)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library `flyspell.el` is normally installed in the folder `.../lisp/textmodes/flyspell.el`.  Within the `flyspell.el` library, there is a variable called `flyspell-mouse-map`.  By default, it is written as follows:

```lisp
(defvar flyspell-mouse-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (if (featurep 'xemacs)
  (define-key map [button2] #'flyspell-correct-word)
      (define-key map [down-mouse-2] #'flyspell-correct-word)
      (define-key map [mouse-2] 'undefined))
    map)
  "Keymap for Flyspell to put on erroneous words.")
```

The original poster seeks to implement `flyspell-correct-word` for a right mouse click with the control key depressed.  So as not to generate an error message if the library `flyspell.el` has not yet been loaded, we use an `eval-after-load` statement.  The alternative would be to use `(require 'flyspell)` before attempting to assign anything  new to the variable `flyspell-mouse-map`.  In other words, the variable must be in existence before we can start using it.  The following code does not remove the prior key assignments, but merely adds two new ones to meet the requirements of the original poster:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "flyspell" '(progn
  (define-key flyspell-mouse-map (kbd "<C-down-mouse-3>") #'flyspell-correct-word)
  (define-key flyspell-mouse-map (kbd "<C-mouse-3>") 'undefined) ))
```

There are a few variations that can be used to write the actual keyboard shortcut, but that is beyond the scope of this answer.