# Appropriate way to skip spell-checking certain macros in AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex, spelling

I want to skip checking inside the macro `\acrshort` (also `\acrlong` and `\acrfull`) from the `glossaries` package.

I tried the following from [the post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150882/37198), where I had some successes in the `\cite...` macros (which I included as follows for the sake of completeness)

```
;; https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150882/37198
(setq ispell-tex-skip-alists
  (list
   (append
(car ispell-tex-skip-alists) 
'(
  ("[^\\]\\$" . "[^\\]\\$")
     ("\\\\textcite"     ispell-tex-arg-end)
     ("\\\\parencite"    ispell-tex-arg-end)
     ("\\\\footcite"     ispell-tex-arg-end)
     ("\\\\fullcite"     ispell-tex-arg-end)
     ("\\\\citetitle"    ispell-tex-arg-end)
     ("\\\\citep"        ispell-tex-arg-end)
     ("\\\\cites"        ispell-tex-arg-end)
     ("\\\\eqref"        ispell-tex-arg-end)
     ("\\\\acrshort" ispell-tex-arg-end)
     ("\\\\acrlong" ispell-tex-arg-end)
     ("\\\\acrfull" ispell-tex-arg-end)
  ;; ("\\\\operatorname\\*"       ispell-tex-arg-end)
  ;; ("\\\\operatorname"       ispell-tex-arg-end)
  ;; ("\\\\mycommadtwo"    ispell-tex-arg-end 2)
  ;; add as many lines like the previous two as you need before the "))"  
  ))
   (cadr ispell-tex-skip-alists)))
```

yet it does not work, i.e., checking inside `\acrshort` is still not skipped. But the following does work,

```
(eval-after-load "tex-ispell"
  '(progn
 (TeX-ispell-skip-setcar
  '(
    ("\\\\acrshort" ispell-tex-arg-end)
    ("\\\\acrlong" ispell-tex-arg-end)
    ("\\\\acrfull" ispell-tex-arg-end)
    ))
  ;; (TeX-ispell-skip-setcdr
  ;;  '(("myverbatim" . "\\\\end{myverbatim}")))
))
```

I do not quite understand why this is happening.

I checked the variable `ispell-tex-skip-alists`, and the difference is that the former method puts the `("\\\\acrshort" ispell-tex-arg-end)` part in the middle of the list, while the latter (successful) method puts the part in the beginning of the list. Is there a more appropriate or more recommended way of doing this? Many thanks!